# Let $X$ be a metric space and $A$ a subset of $X$. Show that $bdry(A)$ is closed in $X$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Working through my first topology book, trying to teach myself.

Abridged definitions given are:

---

***Closed set:** $F$ is closed if $F^c$ is open.*

***Boundary point:** Let $X$ be a metric space and $A⊆X$.
$x_0$ is a boundary point if, for every $r > 0$, $B(x_0,r) ∩ A$ is non-empty and $B(x_0,r) ∩ A^c$ is non-empity. The boundary is the set of all boundary points.*

***Interior point:** Let $X$ be a metric space and $A⊆X$. $x_0$ is an interior point if there exists an $r > 0$ such that $B(x_0,r) ⊆ A$. $A$ is open if every point of $A$ is an interior point.*

---

My answer:

By definition, $bdry(A)$ is closed if $bdry(A)^c$ is open.

So, we want to show that $B(a,r) ∩ bdry(A) = ∅$, for every $a ∈ X - bdry(A)$.

We have two cases:

I) if $a ∈ A$, choose $r$ such that $B(a,r) ⊆ A$ ⟹ $B(a,r) ∩ A^c = ∅$ ⟹ $B(a,r) ∩ bdry(A) = ∅$.

II) if $a ∈ X - A$, choose $r$ such that $B(a,r) ⊆ A^c$ ⟹ $B(a,r) ∩ A= ∅$ ⟹ $B(a,r) ∩ bdry(A) = ∅$.

Thus, $a$ is an interior point of $bdry(A)^c$ ⟹ $bdry(A)^c$ is open ⟹ $bdry(A)$ is closed.

Is this correct? Anything I could improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (I), it should start $a \in \textrm{Int}(A)$. This would give us an $r$ such that $B(a,r) \subseteq A$. If we just pick any $a \in A$, such an $r$ might not exist because $a$ is not necessarily an interior point of $A$. Same thing with (II), we want $a \in \textrm{Int}(X-A)$. Moreover, this is sufficient because $X - bd(A) = \textrm{Int}(A) \cup \textrm{Int}(X-A)$, so we have checked that every $a \in X - A$ is an interior point.

Note, $\textrm{Int}(A)$ denotes the interior of $A$, which is the set of all interior points of $A$.

Comment: Oh, I missed that! Thank you very much.